# How to compute the distributional derivative of $\operatorname{sgn}(x){\rm e}^{-\lvert x \rvert}$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, distribution-theory

> Consider the function $\operatorname{f}(x) = \operatorname{sgn}(x){\rm e}^{-\lvert x \rvert}$ (viewed as a tempered distribution). Show that
>
> $$\operatorname{f}'(x)  = 2\delta(x) - {\rm e}^{-\left\vert x\right\vert}.$$

If I am not mistaken this boils down to computing

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty -\operatorname{sgn}(x)\operatorname{e}^{-\lvert x \rvert} \varphi^\prime(x) \mathrm{d}x$$

for some Schwartz function $\varphi$. I tried to use partial integration, but it did not work. Could you please tell me if I am on the right track?

Comment: And what happens when you do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a simpler way.  Consider $f$ as a piecewise function:

$$x > 0 \implies |x| = x, f(x) = e^{-x} \implies f'(x) = -e^{-x}$$
$$x < 0 \implies |x| = -x, f(x) = -e^{-(-x)} = -e^x \implies f'(x) = -e^{x}$$

Note that you can unite the two sides of the derivative as:

$$x \ne 0 \implies f'(x) = -e^{-|x|}$$

Now we just need to figure out how to treat the case of $x = 0$.  Note that $f$ is discontinuous there.

$$\lim_{x \to 0^-} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0^-} -e^{x} = -1$$
$$\lim_{x \to 0^+} f(x) = \lim_{x \to 0^+} e^{-x} = 1$$

So, if a function's value jumps by 2 at $x = 0$, what does that mean for its distributional derivative?

Comment: Sorry, but I do not get it. I understand your argumentation, but I do not see what this jump by $2$ should entail. I understand that by definition we have (in this case) $\delta(0) = f(0) = 1$. I also understand that we may split up $f$ via $f(x) = \mathbb{1}_{[0,\infty]} (x) f(x) - \mathbb{1}_{(0,-\infty]} (x) f(x)$ and I know the fact that the derivative of the heaviside function is $\delta$. But I do not see how this all fits together.